# Issue Related to inner Query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Following Tables in SQL Server Database:

```
(1) StudentMaster (StudentId, StudentName)

(2) SubjectMaster (SubjectId, SubjectName)

(3) AttendanceMaster (AttendanceId,StudentId,SubjectId,Attendance,Date)


Data in AttendanceMaster can be in Following format :

AttendanceMaster :
           AttendanceId   StudentId   SubjectId    Attendance   Date
              3001          33          1            P           1/1/2011 
              3001          57          2            P1          1/2/2011 
              3001          33          1            P           1/3/2011 
              3001          57          2            P2          1/4/2011 
              3001          33          1            P1          1/5/2011
```

I want to get SubjectWise Individual Attendance Details in Following Format:

```
StudentName  SubjectName   Total(P)  Total(P1)  Total(P2)
 Ghanshyam     Maths         90        10          5
 John          Maths         85        15          5
 Ghanshyam     Science       70        20          15
 John          Science       80        30          5
```

i tried following Query  :

```
select StudentName, SubjectName,
(select count(*) from AttendanceMaster innerAM where innerAM.StudentId = StdM.StudentId and innerAM.SubjectId=SubM.SubjectId and innerAM.Attendance = 'P') as Total(P),
(select count(*) from AttendanceMaster innerAM where innerAM.StudentId = StdM.StudentId and innerAM.SubjectId=SubM.SubjectId and innerAM.Attendance = 'P1') as Total(P1),
(select count(*) from AttendanceMaster innerAM where innerAM.StudentId = StdM.StudentId and innerAM.SubjectId=SubM.SubjectId and innerAM.Attendance = 'P1') as Total(P2)
from AttendanceMaster AM inner join StudentMaster StdM on AM.StudentId = StdM.StudentId
inner join SubjectMaster SubM on AM.SubjectId = SubM.SubjectId
```

I got result but it gets too much time to execute..( about 5 to 6 minut )

```
so what can i do to decrease execution time...
```

and also  is it right way to write a query to get  Total(P),Toal(P1),Total(P2)  ??
please specify other SQL Syntax

Thanks

Comment: if you had primary keys in your table, this search would have been fast.As sql will automatically create index for a primary key.

Comment: yes i do have Primary key.. and also Identity in Id columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. If your query is still running slow, you need to check if there indexes on your table. If you table are large and there're no indexes it still can be slow.

```
select
    StM.StudentName,
    SbjM.SubjectName,
    count(case when AtM.Attendance = 'P' then 1 else null end) as Total(P),
    count(case when AtM.Attendance = 'P1' then 1 else null end) as Total(P1),
    count(case when AtM.Attendance = 'P2' then 1 else null end) as Total(P2)
from StudentMaster  as StM
    inner join AttendanceMaster as AtM on AtM.StudentId = StM.StudentId
    inner join SubjectMaster as SbjM on SbjM.SubjectId = AtM.SubjectId
group by
    StM.StudentName,
    SbjM.SubjectName
```

If columns `Attendance` has no values besides P, P1 and P2, to count total you need just add `count(*) as Total`. If there are other values besides P, P1 and P2, there two ways. First - you can add 
AtM.Attendance in ('P', 'P1', 'P2') in where clause:

```
select
    StM.StudentName,
    SbjM.SubjectName,
    count(case when AtM.Attendance = 'P' then 1 else null end) as Total(P),
    count(case when AtM.Attendance = 'P1' then 1 else null end) as Total(P1),
    count(case when AtM.Attendance = 'P2' then 1 else null end) as Total(P2),
    count(*) as Total
from StudentMaster  as StM
    inner join AttendanceMaster as AtM on AtM.StudentId = StM.StudentId
    inner join SubjectMaster as SbjM on SbjM.SubjectId = AtM.SubjectId
where AtM.Attendance in ('P', 'P1', 'P2')
group by
    StM.StudentName,
    SbjM.SubjectName
```

Or you can write it like this

```
select
    StM.StudentName,
    SbjM.SubjectName,
    count(case when AtM.Attendance = 'P' then 1 else null end) as Total(P),
    count(case when AtM.Attendance = 'P1' then 1 else null end) as Total(P1),
    count(case when AtM.Attendance = 'P2' then 1 else null end) as Total(P2),
    count(case when AtM.Attendance in ('P', 'P1', 'P2') then 1 else null) as Total
from StudentMaster  as StM
    inner join AttendanceMaster as AtM on AtM.StudentId = StM.StudentId
    inner join SubjectMaster as SbjM on SbjM.SubjectId = AtM.SubjectId
group by
    StM.StudentName,
    SbjM.SubjectName
```

Comment: Here in case statement else part is null will that give you the correct count?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i appreciated you..  but what if i want to add another column named Total(P+P1+P2).. what is the synatax for this column ?

Comment: @AnandPhadke, yes, it will be correct, look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997(v=sql.90).aspx - evaluates expression for each row in a group and returns the number of nonnull values

Comment: @ghanshyam.mirani, I've added some queries to an answer, take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select MAX(sm.StudentName) as StudentName,
       MAX(subm.SubjectName) as SubjectName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN am.Attendance='P' then 1 else 0 end) as TotalP,
       SUM(CASE WHEN am.Attendance='P1' then 1 else 0 end) as TotalP1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN am.Attendance='P2' then 1 else 0 end) as TotalP2

from AttendanceMaster am inner join StudentMaster sm
on am.StudentId=sm.StudentId
inner join SubjectMaster subm on am.SubjectId=subm.SubjectId

group by am.StudentId,
         am.SubjectId
```

Comment: do you really need max? I think it's better to group by names. also you need to use `sum` with your case, because `count` will count zeroes. If you want to use `count`, you need to write null in the `else` clause

Comment: I don't mean that it can be done. I mean that your query is incorrect.